# Reading numbers from a .txt file in java and adding them

Tags: java

I have a text file with some account holders and numbers of books they have on loan. I need to read the file, add how many account there are and add the total number of books.

These are the account holders and the total number of books.

> Tim Newton 14
>
> Leon Jones 21
>
> Bill Bob 94
>
> Sarah Gooding 67

```
{
    private int count;
    private File inFile, outFile;
    private Scanner input;
    private String name;
    private PrintWriter output;
    private int total;

    public test(String name, String id, String inFileName, String outFileName) {
        inFile = new File(inFileName);
        if (!inFile.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(inFileName + " does not exist");
        }
        outFile = new File(outFileName);

    }

    public void makeLink() throws FileNotFoundException {
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        output = new PrintWriter(outFile);

    }

    public void processFiles() {
        try {
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                output.println(line);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(" Scanner not assigned");
        }
    }

    public void closeLink() {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(" Scanner not assigned");
        }
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(" PrintWriter not assigned");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the edited code with the scanner answer implemented:

```js
   public void makeLink() throws FileNotFoundException {
     input = new Scanner(inFile);
     output = new PrintWriter(outFile);
     numbers = new Scanner(inFile)

   }


   public void processFiles() {
     try {
       // your current code then
       while (account.hasNextInt()) {
         String line = input.nextLine()
         while (numbers.hasNextInt()) {
           total += numbers.nextInt();
         }
         output.println(line);
       }
     } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       System.out.println(" Scanner not assigned");
     }
   }
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Could you please edit your code according to [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)? It's a bit unreadable.

Comment: Please rephrase your question ,you have a file with account holders....,in order for us to give you a solution, you need to post sample file contents ,the logic to perform these operations will depend on the structure of data stored in the files.

Comment: I know how to read the file and create another one (and also close it)with just the string copied over but I don't know how to add amount of books together or calculate how many account there are.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scanner.hasNextInt()` and `scanner.nextInt()`

You may want to have another scanner that looks for numbers in the file:

```
private Scanner account; // initialise this in makeLink

public void processFiles() {
    try {
        // your current code then
        while (account.hasNextInt()) {
            total += account.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(" Scanner not assigned");
    }
}
```

Note: It is worthwhile to read the java API.

Comment: Thanks for the response, see my edited code in the original post- as you can see I have implemented this code but all it seems to be doing is copying the text however it is not adding any of the numbers up

Comment: @Khaw I used the variable named account to get all the numbers in the file, but it seems you used two variables, account and numbers to do the same thing? Account is not even declared! Why would you do that?